# Why am I getting this error in Python3: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, syntax-error

The title sort of explains itself.

Here's my code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

def log_face(name):
    #create a directory under the training folder with the new persons name
    path = ("./images/train/" + name)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        mkdirexe = ("mkdir " + path)
        subprocess.call([mkdirexe], shell=True)
    
    #copy the most recent image into the new named folder
    copyexe = ("cp image_cam.jpg " + path)
    subprocess.call([copyexe], shell=True)

#if called direct then run the function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = sys.argv[1]
    print(log_face(name))
```

I don't think it's in any of the modules...

Thanks!

Comment: When posting a question, it's better to have a descriptive title and provide a complete description in the text. In this case, you should have included a stack trace of the error message, so people can see what line caused it. It's probably the `argv[1]`, are you actually passing an argument to the script?

Comment: Side-note: `log_face` returns nothing, so `print(log_face(name))` is equivalent to just calling `log_face`, then doing `print(None)`, which is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely `name = sys.argv[1]` is where you're running into the IndexError.

You're calling the first command line argument without passing anything in. It doesn't prompt you for any input and will fail with an IndexError.

**Edit:** Didn't see Grismar's comment!